# Cannot Create Audio Stream from Input Stream

Tags: java, inputstream, wav, audio-player

I am trying to get a sound file (.wav) to play when a button is clicked. The calls are all made correctly. When I click the button, an IOException is printed. This is the code for the method that starts the music:

```
public void playSound(String path) {

//M:\Programming\workspace\testing\music.wav  <--- String path
    InputStream in;
    AudioStream as = null;

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(path);
        as = new AudioStream(in);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Audio file not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect input.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
}
```

This is the error:

```
java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream
at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at GameWindow.playSound(GameWindow.java:484)
at GameWindow$13.mouseReleased(GameWindow.java:385)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried numerous methods to play audio files that I've found on Google, but all return this same error. What do I need to do to fix this? And if there is a better way to work with audio files, can you provide any resources to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instantiating a `WaveFileReader` (package `com.sun.media.sound`) - this should be used to read your file. If you get an `UnsupportedAudioFileException` then probably you have a corrupt wav file - try with a different one.

Comment: I guess it was a corrupted file. The one I was using I renamed to .wav -- deleted that and downloaded a new one. Works perfectly now.